# Error in my code's for loop - the error message states "input string not in correct format"

Tags: c#

```
//Declaring variables
int limit = 10;
Double x = 0, total = 0, userInput, final;
String input;
WriteLine("Enter a number to show multiplication table:  ");
input = ReadLine();
userInput = Convert.ToInt32(input);
 //While loop to accept multiple user inputs
for (x = 0; x <= limit; x++)
{
    total = x;
    final = userInput * x;
    WriteLine("{0} times {1} equals (2}", userInput, x, final);
}
```

I have been working on this for a while. What I am trying to accomplish is when a user inputs a number the code will create a multiplication table for numbers 1-10. For example, the code will display 7 time 1 equals 7. I tried to create a for loop to use the WriteLine statement until x less than or equal to the limit. The x++ statement is meant to add one to x each time the loop is executed. Have I misunderstood how for loops work? I have checked through my code for minor syntax error but can not find the solution to this problem. I am sorry if this is not what this site is for as this is my first time posting here. Thank you for all of the replies in advance as I am new to programming and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple typo.
"{" Instead of "(" as below:

```
"{0} times {1} equals {2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the line:

```
WriteLine("{0} times {1} equals (2}", userInput, x, final);
```

The second placeholder has a typo and it should be `{2}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple error:

```
WriteLine("{0} times {1} equals {2}", userInput, x, final);
```

If using C# 6.0 or later, you can use String interpolation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

```
WriteLine($"{userInput} times {x} equals {final}");
// Both calls produce the same output
```